# Determine if array size is changed from previous value - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The code is as follows

```
 previous_values = [
  {
    : id=>1,
    : name=>"fruits",
    : categories=>[
      {
        : id=>1,
        : name=>"orange",
        : qty=>7
      },
      {
        : id=>2,
        : name=>"apple",
        : qty=>7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    : id=>2,
    : name=>"vegetables",
    : categories=>[
      {
        : id=>1,
        : name=>"spinach",
        : qty=>7
      },
      {
        : id=>2,
        : name=>"carrot",
        : qty=>7
      }
    ]
  }
]

new_values = [
      {
        : id=>1,
        : name=>"fruits",
        : categories=>[
          {
            : id=>1,
            : name=>"orange",
            : qty=>5
          },
          {
            : id=>2,
            : name=>"apple",
            : qty=>7
          },
          {
            : id=>3,
            : name=>"guava",
            : qty=>7
          }
        ]
      },
  {
    : id=>2,
    : name=>"vegetables",
    : categories=>[
      {
        : id=>1,
        : name=>"spinach",
        : qty=>7
      },
      {
        : id=>2,
        : name=>"carrot",
        : qty=>7
      }
    ]
  }
    ]
```

I need to determine if the size of **categories** is changed in the new values.

In this case, the size of fruit categories has changed in fruits whereas size of vegetable categories has not changed.
So in general, i need to get size_changed as true since one of the category size has been changed

I have implemented this as follows.

```
    size_changed = false
    previous_values.each do |p|

      current_val = new_values.to_a.find { |nv| nv.id == p.id }
      if current_val.categories.map(&:id).sort != p.categories.map(&:id).sort
        size_changed = true
      end
    end
    size_changed
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this? Something like a one liner?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `piece.piece_upids` here ?

Comment: I have changed it.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the size alone is changed or need to compare the ids as well?

Answer (score 0):

This returns true if the size changed:

```
previous_values[0][:categories].size != new_values[0][:categories].size
```

Answer (score 0):

**New answer for the updated question**

This returns true if the size of categories is changed:

```
previous_values.each.map{|val| val[:categories].size}.sum != new_values.each.map{|val| val[:categories].size}.sum
```